# How to access variable inside React Component? Initialized it outside Component

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, reactjs, object

I'm currently a beginner working on a project in React/Redux. I'm trying to call JSON from an API file, save it as an array of objects, and then pass it into another file to start pulling data out of it. I recently got stuck in one place

Below is my class, which is accessing the JSON data and pulling it out to put into an array. I initialized the array outside of the class, but it's not being written to. I'm not really sure how to 'throw' the array that I need out of my class.

numberendpoint.json (an array of objects)

```
[
    {
        color: "red",
        value: "#f00"
    },
    {
        color: "green",
        value: "#0f0"
    },
    {
        color: "blue",
        value: "#00f"
    },
    {
        color: "cyan",
        value: "#0ff"
    },
    {
        color: "magenta",
        value: "#f0f"
    },
    {
        color: "yellow",
        value: "#ff0"
    },
    {
        color: "black",
        value: "#000"
    }
]
```

In index.js

```
let productJSON = [] //initialize productJSON array here

class Hue extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            elements: [],
            productJSON: []
        };
    }

    componentWillMount() {
        fetch('numberendpoint.json')
        .then(results => {
            return results.json();
        }).then(data => {
            let colorArray = [] //initialize array to receive json data
            for (let i =0; i < data.length; i++) {
                colorArray.push(data[i])
            }
            productJSON = JSON.stringify(productArray) //here is where I try to assign the productJSON array
            let elements = data.map((rainbow) => {
                return (
                    <div key={rainbow.results}>
                        <p>{raindow.color}</p>
                        <p>{rainbow.value}</p>
                    </div>
                )
            })
            this.setState({elements: elements});
            console.log("state", this.state.elements[0]);
        })
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
            <div className="container2">
            {this.state.elements}
        </div>
        </div>
    )}
}
```

How can I access the JSONproduct array? or alternatively, how do I 'pop' it out of this class so I can use it?

Update: used the solution suggested by Rahamin. Now I have this code below, all contained within the the "Hue" class. But I'm still getting errors.

```
import React from 'react'

const TIMEOUT = 100

let productJSON;
class Hue extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      products: [],
    };
    this.getColors = this.getColors.bind(this)
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    fetch('http://tech.work.co/shopping-cart/products.json')
      .then(results => {
        return results.json();
      }).then(data => {

    let colorArray = []
    for (let i =0; i < data.length; i++) {
      colorArray.push(data[i])
      }
    console.log("jsonproduct=" + JSON.stringify(productArray))

    productJSON = JSON.stringify(productArray)

   this.setState({productJSON: productJSON});

  });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div className="container2">
          {this.state.productJSON}
        </div>
      </div>
      )
    }
}


export default {
  getProducts: (cb, timeout) => setTimeout(() => cb(({ productJSON: value})), timeout || TIMEOUT), // here is where I am getting an error -- "value" is undefined. I'm not sure I was meant to put "value" there or something else...very new to React so its conventions are still foreign to me.
  buyProducts: (payload, cb, timeout) => setTimeout(() => cb(), timeout || TIMEOUT)
}
```

Comment: Data that needs to be accessed globally should be stored in the redux state. If you just need that data in a child component, pass it as props. I highly suggest you check out some redux react tutorial before getting started

Comment: Can you explain why you don't think what you've tried is working? I can't see any code that attempts to use the productJSON variable outside of the class

Comment: `fetch` should be called at `componentDidMount`

Comment: Thank you @klugjo, I have a very short time to pick up React-Redux so I'm still learning all about state.

Comment: @MartinBooth you are correct, I don't think I was actually attempting to call it outside of the method. I'm next going to try to pass it to another component, so we'll see how that goes.

Answer (score 0):

```
let productJSON = [] //initialize productJSON array here

class Hue extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            elements: [],
            productJSON: []
        };
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        fetch('numberendpoint.json')
        .then(res => {
            this.setState({elements: res.data});
        })
    }

render() {
            if(this.state.elements.length > 0){ //once the data is fetched
              return (
                <div>
                <div className="container2">
                {this.state.elements.map((rainbow) => {
                return (
                    <div key={rainbow.results}>
                        <p>{raindow.color}</p>
                        <p>{rainbow.value}</p>
                    </div>
                )
            })}
            </div>
            </div>
        )
            }
           else{ // initial render
             return null;
           }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand why you are trying to put array OUTSIDE of a class but I think you need to understand when each event gets called in React.

`componentDidMount` is an event that gets called when all the components have mounted in the class. So at this stage, `render()` function has already run. Which means your `productJSON` is undefined at this stage. What you really wanna do is that make sure your component changes when the state gets updated to something other than `undefined`.

Try the following code.

```
let productJSON = [] //initialize productJSON array here

class Hue extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            elements: [],
        };
    }

    componentWillMount() {
        fetch('numberendpoint.json')
        .then(results => {
            return results.json();
        }).then(data => {
            let colorArray = [] //initialize array to receive json data
            for (let i =0; i < data.length; i++) {
                colorArray.push(data[i])
            }
            this.setState({productJSON:colorArray});

            let elements = data.map((rainbow) => {
                return (
                    <div key={rainbow.results}>
                        <p>{raindow.color}</p>
                        <p>{rainbow.value}</p>
                    </div>
                )
            })
            this.setState({elements: elements});
            console.log("state", this.state.elements[0]);
        })
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
            <div className="container2">
            {this.state.productJSON ? 'state not ready' : this.state.productJSON} //this is the important part. It will render this.state.productJSON only when it is a truthy value.
        </div>
        </div>
    )}
}
```

Given that you do get a valid `colorArray` from your call, this will work.